# Making a variable accessible to handler in salvo

Tags: rust

How can I make the current game available to my request handler in Salvo?

The current game needs to be able to change, as it contains the current game state inside it. I don't need any support for multiple games running concurrently.

I would be excited about a solution where I can pass it into the handler somehow from the main function, but am open to anything.

My current attempt at this involves all of this code:

```rust
struct Config {
    pub current_game: Option<game::Game>,
}

impl Config {
    pub fn current() -> Arc<Config> {
        CURRENT_CONFIG.with(|c| c.read().unwrap().clone())
    }
    pub fn make_current(self) {
        CURRENT_CONFIG.with(|c| *c.write().unwrap() = Arc::new(self))
    }
}

impl Default for Config {
    fn default() -> Config {
        Config {current_game: None}
    }
}

thread_local! {
    static CURRENT_CONFIG: RwLock<Arc<Config>> = RwLock::new(Default::default());
}
```

This works, but it's a lot of overhead and boilerplate code. Is there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is future Googler!

Because the handlers are secretly structs behind the scenes, you can make your own struct implementing the Handler trait, and give it a variable that will be available every time the handler runs!

There is a catch though, you cannot mutate it in your handler function, because your handler function can't get a mutable reference to self. This can be solved by putting it in a RwLock.

```rust
pub struct GamePostHandler {
    // Contained within a RwLock so that we can
    // modify it from the non-mutable context of our handle function
    game: RwLock<Option<game::Game>>
}


#[async_trait]
impl Handler for GamePostHandler {
    async fn handle(&self, _req: &mut Request, _depot: &mut Depot, _res: &mut Response, _ctrl: &mut FlowCtrl) {
        // Handle function
    }
}
```

It may be super hacky, but sometimes that is all you need.